# Injecting an object InRequestScope into a ValidationAttribute via Ninject throws error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

Ninject now enables property injection into ValidationAttribute (https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Injection-of-validators). It works great, UNTIL you use bind the object InRequestScope().

So, here is what I think is happening. ValidationAttribute are implemented as singletons in ASP.NET.

1. The first time an attribute is instantiated, Ninject properly populates the injected property.
2. The object that was injected is disposed when the current request ends
3. Upon the next request, accessing the injected property throws an error because it has been disposed.

Ninject does not try to populate the injected property because the validation attribute is never re-instantiated.

Does this make sense? Does anyone have any idea for a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct.

If you really need a dependency in request scope then you have to inject a [factory](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki) for the dependency instead of the dependency itself and use it to get a new instance during evaluation.